# Conditional expectation of functions

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $\Omega=[0,1]^2, \mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]^2}, P=\lambda_{[0,1]^2}$. Find $E(f|g)$ if $f(x,y)=x^2y, g(y)=y$.

I have no idea even how to start this exercise. Should we use definition, but I do not know the set for integration.

Comment: The notation is unclear - one takes the (conditonal) expectation of a random variable, not a density function...

Comment: This is exact notation from my exercise I am also not sure what it means.